# Summation sign inside an expected value

Tags: probability, summation

Would it be correct to assume $E\left[\sum U_i\right] = nE[U_i]$?

I am trying to show that $E[∑(U_i - E[U])^2] = (n-1)(\text{sample variance)}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $\mathbb E(U_i)$ does not depend of $i$ yes. The expectation is linear.

Comment: thanks you for your help! Yes E(Ui) doesn't depend on i, U is the variable capturing unexplained factors in a regression model.